# Tomcat WAR file deploy failure in Windows

Tags: java, tomcat, extract, web-deployment, war

I have an application running in a tomcat container in Windows environment.
When I have to update the application, the tomcat windows service is stopped, new ROOT.war file is copied in the webapps folder and tomcat service is restarted.

Sometimes it happens that the ROOT.war extraction fails and the extracted ROOT folder has only few subfolder and few files. Obviously the following application startup fails.
To solve this problem I have to stop tomcat, delete ROOT folder and run in again to let tomcat re-extract the ROOT.war again from the beginning.

I cannot understand why sometimes it happens and sometimes no. However, it makes impossibile to me to create an automatic update. It is too risky.

Do you have any idea why it can happen?

Comment: Do you  have eny error messages in the log ? I guess either tomcat or the application is leaking open files/streams/etc which prevents the old files to be deleted. Search for `antiResourceLocking` https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html

Comment: This has happened previously to me, and the reason was some file or streams were not closed (i.e. they were still in use by tomcat process). So deleting those resources was being prevented and thus new WAR was not getting deployed until tomcat was stopped.

Comment: I believe this question has its merits and the OP is incurring in a race condition (he is modifying the WAR file, while Tomcat is unzipping the new version), hence I vote to reopen.

Comment: Is there any way to monitor all streams opened by tomcat in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Resources are not released. So, when you try to update the existing war file, tomcat is not able to delete the older files before deployment/redeployment.

To resolve this issue, ensure that:

1. The application is not open/running on web browser.
2. You're not stuck in debug mode when you click on update.
3. All processes/requests are completed before redeployment.
4. All files/streams are closed within the code.
5. When all else fails, you may want to **stop the application**. Then update. There are ways to stop applications on tomcat using command line, batch files, etc. You can then automate the process.

If you want a more reliable way to do this, you may use jrebel or a free version of the same. There are other ways to update code. Basically, standalone tomcat is not worth anything more than a development server.

Comment: The update process stop the tomcat Windows service, overwrite the WAR file, then the service is started again. So I don't think there is something running if the windows service is stopped. i'm not sure how commons daemon works, but I think it signals service stopped only after the full application stop.

Comment: @Tobia: you should update your question with this information. The question doesn't mention whether Tomcat is up or down when you modify `ROOT.war`.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark**: if you are updating the application while Tomcat is running you need to either:

- use Tomcat Manager to deploy it,
- call [`tryAddServiced`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/76da8deac37071e8a891580d74ba1322c7a2da2c/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/HostConfig.java#L325) (before Tomcat 9.0 `addServiced/isServiced`) before any modification to the `webapps` directory and `removeServiced` afterwards. This can be done through JMX on the bean `Catalina:type=Deployer,host=<your_host_name>`,
- replace the WAR file (almost) atomically: e.g. deleting the old one and moving (renaming) the new one from another location on the same filesystem should work.

which prevents Tomcat from immediately deploying the application until the copy operation is finished.

To prevent the OS from locking the files in the `webapps/ROOT` folder you have two options:

1. Use `antiResourceLocking="true"` as already suggested by [Svetlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694711/tomcat-war-file-deploy-failure-in-windows#comment121401065_68694711), which basically forces Tomcat to copy `webapps/ROOT` to a uniquely named temporary directory before deployment (the copy will be locked, `webapps/ROOT` will not),
2. Use [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) by naming your WAR files: `ROOT##001.war`, `ROOT##002.war`, etc. This is basically an explicit version of the `antiResourceLocking` feature with the additional advantage of letting clients transition fluently between the old and new app version.

Comment: Tomcat is not running when I want to update. Sorry if it was not clear in the question.

Comment: Do you have enough space on the filesystem to fit the unzipped WAR file? How do you stop the service and check that it is already stopped?

Comment: I'm sure about the disk space (but good idea, you never know!). The service is stopped usign windows OpenServiceManager handlers, I run the stop command and then wait until status is SERVICE_STOPPED